# Derivative Notation: Let $f(x)=x$. Is $f′(x^2)=1$ or is $f′(x^2)=2x$?

Tags: derivatives, notation

Let $f(x)=x$.

Is $f'(x^2)=1$ or is $f'(x^2)=2x$?

In other words, using this notation, are we evaluating the derivative at a $x^2$?

Comment: @KM101 Why does the chain rule not apply to your sine example. In other words, why is $f'(x^5) = (5x^4)cos(x^5) $ wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you consider the function $f$ of a variable $x$, then $f'$ is likewise a function. When you write $f'(a)$, you evaluate that function at $a$. If $a$ happens to be $x^2$, then you evaluate at $x^2$. It has *nothing* to do with differentiating with respect to $a$ or $x^2$ or anything else. So, in your example, $f'(a)=1$ no matter what you put in for $a$ when $f(x)=x$.

If you consider $g(x)=x^2$ and the composition $(f\circ g)(x) = f(x^2)$, then
$(f\circ g)'(x) = f'(g(x))g'(x) = f'(x^2)\cdot 2x$.

Comment: So you are saying if $F = f \circ g$, $f(x)=x$, $g(x)=x^2$, then $F'(x) = 2x$. This means $f'(x^2) = \frac{F'(x)}{g'(x)} = \frac{2x}{2x} = 1$. Am I correct?

Comment: Sure. The problem with this, Snowball, is that your computation doesn't work when $x=0$, but $f'(x^2)=1$ for all values of $x$.

Comment: Sorry: I had a typo from trying to do this in a hurry. Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're getting hung up on the notation, which is understandable because this notation can mean different things in different contexts.

$f(x)$ is always a function of the variable $x$.

$f'(x)$ is the derivative of $f(x)$. Perhaps you could think of this as saying $f$ has already been differentiated so all we're interested in is its argument. The outermost function of $f'(x^2)$ and $f'(\sqrt{x})$ is the same, i.e. $f'(\cdot)$; the only thing changing is whether we substitute $x^2$ or $\sqrt{x}$. For example, if $f(x)=x^3$, then $f'(x)=3x^2$ and $f'(x^2)=3(x^2)^2$. This explains how Ted's answer has the derivative of $F(x)=(f\circ g)(x)=x^2$ computed as $F'(x)=(f\circ g)'(x)=2x$. Note that the term $f'(x^2)$ was (unintuitively) $1$, since $f'(x)=1$ for all $x$.

Conversely, $\left(f(x)\right)'$ has the derivative on the outside so it is the last step. So this puts more emphasis on differentiating what's inside the brackets. For instance $\left(f(x^2)\right)'$ would usually mean that we've taken the function $f(x^2)$ and are *then* differentiating that wrt. $x$. This is different from $f'(x^2)$, where we *first* differentiated and then substituted $x^2$. For example, if $f(x)=x^3$, then $f(x^2)=(x^2)^3=x^6$ and $\left(f(x^2)\right)'=6x^5$. This explains how Yves' answer has the derivative of $F(x)=x^2$ computed as $F'(x)=(x^2)'=2x$.

Hopefully this addresses your original question. When we define $f(x)=x$, the expression $f'(x^2)$ means *first* take the derivative ($=1$) and *then* substitute $x^2$, which makes no difference in this case since the derivative is constant.

Comment: Having taught university mathematics for 40 years or so, I absolutely discourage the notation $(f(x^2))'$ for the reason that it leads to such confusion. I want to emphasize that you should differentiate functions and not formulas. But in the setting of engineering calculus, people get lazy and write such things.

Comment: Indeed. To be honest, I'd normally opt for $\frac{d}{dx}\left(\cdot\right)$ to be unambiguous. I'm not completely sure what you mean by 'differentiate functions and not formulas' though?

Comment: The whole Leibniz notation is horribly ambiguous and misleading. When you write $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{dy}{du}\dfrac{du}{dx}$ the letter $y$ represents two totally different functions. Again, this is differentiating formulas without understanding functions. One is a composition of functions; the notation totally obscures that.

Comment: I meant Leibniz as an operator, not as a function.